# Skipping array items based in a list of intervals

Tags: python, list, tuples

So I'm trying to code a program for my girlfriend in python to automate the process of getting all musical notes in a given scale.

I want to make the list of notes:

```
notes =  ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
```

skip their indexes by this set of intervals:

```
intervals = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
```

Thank you in advance!

I tried to do it manually but I really want to automate all the process.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modular arithmetic for this
Similar to what Edo Akse wrote -

```py
notes =  ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
intervals = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
idx = 3

for interval in intervals:
    print(notes[idx])
    idx += interval
    idx %= len(notes)
```

result

```
D#
F
F#
G#
A#
B
C#
```

Answer (score 0):

use an index for the notes, start where you want, and add each interval to the index in a loop. Subtract length of the list if you're past the end to loop the notes list.

```py
notes =  ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#', 'E', 'F', 'F#', 'G', 'G#', 'A', 'A#', 'B']
intervals = [2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2]
idx = 3


for interval in intervals:
    print(notes[idx])
    idx += interval
    if idx > len(notes):
        idx -= len(notes)
```

output

```
D#
F
F#
G#
A#
B
C#
```

Comment: That’s almost all I needed, but if I wanted to start the scale at the second index, the list wont loop to the start again, do you know any way I can do that?

Comment: you mean start from the second index in the notes, or second index in the intervals?

Comment: ah wait, I understand. You can do that by adding a check at the end of the loop to see if you're past the length of the notes list. If so, subtract the length of the notes list. See updated answer. I'm not 100% sure if that's how music scales work though.